# Drawing tilemap is lowering my fps to a crawl

Tags: c++, frame-rate, sfml

Okay, I'm trying to get my fps to 60, but right now it's at around 20. What can I do to this code to speed it up? Note: this is c++ using sfml.

```
    App.Clear();
    for(int x = 0; x < lv.width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < lv.height; y++){

            int tileXCoord = 0;
            int tileYCoord = 0;
            int tileSheetWidth = tilemapImage.GetWidth() / lv.tileSize;

            if (lv.tile[x][y] != 0)
            {
                tileXCoord = lv.tile[x][y] % tileSheetWidth;
                tileYCoord = lv.tile[x][y] / tileSheetWidth;
            }

            tilemap.SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(tileXCoord * lv.tileSize, tileYCoord * lv.tileSize, (tileXCoord * lv.tileSize) + lv.tileSize, (tileYCoord * lv.tileSize) + lv.tileSize));
            tilemap.SetPosition(x * lv.tileSize, y * lv.tileSize);
            App.Draw(tilemap);
        }
    }

    playerSprite.SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(player.width * player.frame, player.height * player.state,
                                   (player.width * player.frame) + player.width, (player.height * player.state) + player.height));
    playerSprite.SetPosition(player.x, player.y);

    App.Draw(playerSprite);

    if(player.walking){
        if(player.frameDelay >= 0)
            player.frameDelay--;

        if(player.frameDelay <= 0){

            player.frame++;
            player.frameDelay = 10;

            if(player.frame >= 4)
                player.frame = 0;
        }
    }


    for(int x = 0; x < lv.width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < lv.height; y++){

            int tileXCoord = 0;
            int tileYCoord = 0;
            int tileSheetWidth = tilemapImage.GetWidth() / lv.tileSize;

            if (lv.ftile[x][y] != 0)
            {
                tileXCoord = lv.ftile[x][y] % tileSheetWidth;
                tileYCoord = lv.ftile[x][y] / tileSheetWidth;
            }

            tilemap.SetSubRect(sf::IntRect(tileXCoord * lv.tileSize, tileYCoord * lv.tileSize, (tileXCoord * lv.tileSize) + lv.tileSize, (tileYCoord * lv.tileSize) + lv.tileSize));
            tilemap.SetPosition(x * lv.tileSize, y * lv.tileSize);
            App.Draw(tilemap);
        }
    }


    App.Display();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're iterating over the pixels of your level, instead of over the tiles. Rewrite it like

```
 ///get the width of a tile
// get the height of a tile
int tileWidth = tilemapImage.getWidth();
int tileHeight = tilemapImage.getHeight();

//find the number of tiles vertically and horizontally, by dividing
// the level width by the number of tiles
int xTiles = lv.width / tileWidth;
int yTiles = lv.height / tileHeight();

for (int x = 0; x < xTiles; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < yTiles; y++) {
        // Do your calculations here

        //ie: if(Walking) { draw_walk_anim; }
        // draw_tile[x][y];

        tilemap.SetPosition(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack expertise in the area, but you're drawing your tilemap for every tile, based on the parameters it's taking, it looks like it's redrawing the entire tilemap even though it's changed at most a single tile.

How would only calling App.Draw(tilemap); after every row, or perhaps after you've set the entire screen affect things.

Comment: Then I'd only get 1 tile drawn per row, or screen.

Comment: Again, I lack expertise with this. But it looks like the two tilemap.Set... lines configure portions of the tilemap object. App.Draw(tilemap) then draws it. Unless the changes to the tilemap object are lost between iterations, I don't see why that would be the case. If I'm completely wrong: just ignore me, I'll be quiet now.